# Where are contract functions implemented on bscscan verified contract

Tags: etherscan, bsc

The following functions are defined on a contract posted on BSC scan; however, the implementations don't seem to be available.

```
contract Acc {
    function acc_Transfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) public;
    function acc_balanceOf(address who) public view returns (uint256);
    function acc_setup(address token, uint256 supply) public returns (bool);
}
```

How is this possible?

Here is the link to the contract on bscscan: https://bscscan.com/address/0x52dff9c835dbf7675e9338ddcfdafdbd83cf9ebd#code

Answer (score 0):

The contract `Acc` is only used as an interface so it doesn't need a code to be associated with the contract.

If you look at the constructor

```
constructor(address _acc)
```

it receives an address that will be used as the implementation for the `Acc` contract.

The deployed contract uses `0x7EA6221d92a08ae6E3e89b16Ac81736c517B9549` as the `Acc` implementation. That contract isn't verified, and no code is provided.

I suggest to not use that contract it is highly suspicious. You shouldn't trust a contract without source code.